# Referencing an Excel file, workbook, worksheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

All,
I have been struggling to simply reference an Excel file so that I can extract its data into a new worksheet automatically.

I know this means to create a new Excel file and its items:

```
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
        Excel.Range oRng;



            //Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;
            //Get a new workbook.
            oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
```

But this is where I am lost...I want the user to select another Excel file through a file dialog and then I want to copy data from said file into the new workbook above.

Ex: New file, user selects "MyExcel.csv". **How would I reference this so that I can, say, copy Column A into the new worksheet?** Whatever works with C#.

Comment: See this. I have given an example [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/23/opening-an-excel-file/) It is in VB.Net but can be asily converted to C#

Comment: And [Copying and Pasting Range](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/05/03/copying-and-pasting-range/) as well.

Comment: How do u convert to C#?

Comment: For begginers, [CodeTranslator](https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/) should help :)

Comment: If u know, how do I make the file paths dictated by the user, not within the CS file?

Comment: I have shown that in the first link. See the 2nd code which talks about `openFileDialog`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you want to copy one column from the csv file and paste in the new excel file.

First, I convert the csv file to datatable.

Second, I select the specific column and convert one column to datatable.

Third, I convert the datatable to the new excel file.

You can try the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "D:\\t.csv";
            DataTable table = ReadCsv(path);
            table= new DataView(table).ToTable(false, "Tests");
            ExportToExcel(table, "D:\\t.xlsx");
        }
        public static DataTable ReadCsv(string path)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
            objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = objWB.Worksheets[1];

            int rows = objSHT.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            int cols = objSHT.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int noofrow = 1;

            for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
            {
                string colname = objSHT.Cells[1, c].Text;
                dt.Columns.Add(colname);
                noofrow = 2;
            }

            for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
                {
                    dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Text;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            objWB.Close();
            objXL.Quit();
            return dt;
        }

        public static void ExportToExcel( DataTable tbl, string excelFilePath = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tbl == null || tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                // single worksheet
                Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                // column headings
                for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

                // rows
                for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // to do: format datetime values before printing
                    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tbl.Rows[i][j];
                    }
                }

                // check file path
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelFilePath))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        workSheet.SaveAs(excelFilePath);
                        excelApp.Quit();
                        Console.WriteLine("Excel file saved!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                                            + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                { // no file path is given
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Initial csv file.

[image]

The excel file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
***Make sure your manage your Nugets and add the reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" --> (References (Right click) --> Manage Nuget Packages --> Browse --> "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" --> Install)***

 
**Note:** This is is a copy paste into the same worksheet. To copy the data into another worksheet from another file just pass the "worksheet" as parameter to the method and paste it there.

---

```
public class Excel1
    {
        private readonly string excelSufix = ".xlsx";

        private readonly string excelFilePrefix = "..."; //Where you excel file is located

        private string getFilePath(string fileName)
        {
            return excelFilePrefix + fileName + excelSufix; //returns the file path by the given file name
        }

        public void CopyPaste(string fileName, int worksheet, string toCopyRange, string whereInsertRange)
        {
            //Range should look like = "A:C" or "D:F"
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            var workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(getFilePath(fileName));
            var workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[worksheet];

            var toCopy = workSheet.Range[toCopyRange];
            var whereInsert = workSheet.Range[whereInsertRange];

            whereInsert.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, toCopy.Cut());
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit:** You could add a constructor to the class where you pass the file Path and some class variables which reference the file, the worksheet etc etc... In this case, you will have independent objects for each file